# Change plotting order of categories of data in tmap map R

Tags: r, r-sp, tmap

I am plotting some spatial data in R using the `tmap` package. I define breaks and plot color in the `tm_dots` function. I'd like to be able to define the plot order of the categories so that they are defined by the category (highest category on top, second highest below that, etc.). I need to be able to see clearly where the highest category points are. I know this could be achieved with multiple spatial point data frames, but is there another less clunky way? Below is an example using the meuse data. I make the points huge so they overlap. So ideally here in the plot the plot order would be: blue, green, orange, red.

```
libary(tmap)
library(sp)

data("meuse")

coordinates(meuse) <- c("x","y")

tm_layout() +
  tm_shape(meuse) + tm_dots("cadmium", breaks = c(1,2,3,4,Inf), palette = "-Spectral", auto.palette.mapping = FALSE,
                            size = 1) + 
  tm_legend(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Turns out the default plot order is the original data frame row order. To make the categories plot in the correct order, I create a numeric factor variable for the categories and sort the original data frame by it.

```
libary(tmap)
library(sp)
library(dplyr)

data("meuse")

meuse <- meuse %>% 
         mutate(cat = base::cut(cadmium, breaks = c(-Inf,1,2,3,4,Inf), 
                         labels = c(1,2,3,4,5))) %>% 
         arrange(cat)

coordinates(meuse) <- c("x","y")

tm_layout() +
  tm_shape(meuse) + tm_dots("cadmium", breaks = c(1,2,3,4,Inf), palette = "-Spectral", auto.palette.mapping = FALSE,
                            size = 1) + 
  tm_legend(legend.outside = TRUE)
```

[image]